# Ignore a request error from an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular application that uses GraphQL as API structure. When an error is thrown on the backend, the request has a 500 status on it, but still returns a standard JSON (ableit with an "errors" array). However, this 500 status triggers an error in the observable when I only subscribe to it. I want to ignore the error that is thrown and instead just check for the error array on the response. My first approach:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.loginGQL.watch({email, password}).valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
            
            if(!result.errors || result.errors.length === 0) {
                this.authData.next(result.data.login);
            } else {
                this.error.next(result.errors[0].message);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tried this approach to try to solve the problem:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.loginGQL.fetch({email, password}).pipe(map(result => 
            result.data
        ), catchError(
            err => {
                console.log(err);
                return err.message;
            }
        )).subscribe(
            (finalResult: string | AuthData) => {
                if(typeof finalResult !== "string") {
                    this.authData.next(finalResult);
                } else {
                    console.log(finalResult);
                    this.error.next(finalResult);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

This however not only throws away the response, but the error message also somehow gets split up into single letters. Not the best experience.

What would be the best approach do to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in using the [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operator, but one of it's requirement is it *must* return an observable. And since you're returning `err.message`, each character of the string is emitted individually. Instead you could use the RxJS [`of()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) function to return the error as a `next` notification. It'll be emitted to the `next` callback of the subscription. Try the following

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

login(email: string, password: string) {
  this.loginGQL.fetch({ email, password }).pipe(
    map(result => result.data), 
    catchError(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return of(err);     // <-- you could also return the required array here
    })
  ).subscribe(
    (finalResult: string | AuthData) => {
      if (typeof finalResult !== "string") {
        this.authData.next(finalResult);
      } else {
        console.log(finalResult);
        this.error.next(finalResult);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: This solution not only seems like the most orthodox one according to best practices (I have heard of the 'of' function before when I did an Angular course, I never learned really what exactly it does though), but it also worked almost straight up. The only change I made to the code is this: ```

return of(err.networkError.error.errors[0].message);

```

This returns the original message from the server, instead of the error message generated on the frontend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.subscribe()` has a couple of overloads that handle error scenarios. The `subscribe` method takes up to 3 arguments (`next`, `error`, `complete`). We can utilize the second `error` argument to handle intercept the exception and handle it as we want. [More info](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable)

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.loginGQL.watch({email, password}).valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
            this.authData.next(result.data.login);
        }, errorResult => {
           if(errorResult.errors && errorResult.errors.length > 0) {
             this.error.next(errorResult.errors[0].message);
           }
        });
    }
```

Note that I removed the `if(!result.errors || result.errors.length === 0)` conditional from the `next` function argument. If the `next` or `complete` function is invoked then no error was thrown. I left the inverse of the conditional in the `error` function since I prefer to have "sanity checks" in code to prevent random null reference errors.

Comment: How is that solving his issue?

Comment: I'm confused. As I understood it, the original question is that a 500 triggers an error on the subscription and they want to know how to ignore the error and check only for error array on the response. This answer uses the `error` argument to handle any errors from the observable and verifies using the inverse logic from the original attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try something like this:

```js
src$.pipe(
  catchError(err => {

    // throwing another error so that `retryWhen` will intercept it
    const sources = [throwError(err)];

    // send the `errors` array as a `next` notification
    err.status === 500 && sources.unshift(of(err.errors))

    return concat(...sources);
  }),

  // make sure the subscription is keept alive after `500` errors
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(filter(err => err.status === 500))),
)
```